# BeautifulSoup getting content behind multiple <div> levels

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get the time data behind two "divs" with BeautifulSoup?

```
<div>
<div>
6:00.00
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.energystorageexchange.org/projects/2") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

rows = soup.select("div.div")

for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

but it doesn't work that easy.

The full HTML sample:

```
<div class='row'>
<hr class='border zeropadding zeromargin'>
<div class='col-md-6 zeropadding'>
<label class='new_font'>Duration at Rated Power (HH:MM)</label>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6 new_font'>
<div></div>
<div>
<div>
6:00.00
</div>
</div>

</div>
</hr>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<hr class='border zeropadding zeromargin'>
<div class='col-md-6 zeropadding new_font'>
<label class='new_font'>Weblink1</label>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6 new_font'>
<div>
<div class='show_value'>
<a href="http://www.gillsonions.com/node/192" target='_new' class='boldbluelink'>http://www.gillsonions.com/node/192</a>
</div>
</div>
```

It's from https://www.energystorageexchange.org/projects/2

Thanks for any help.

2nd Question:

I would also like to capture size in kW from

```
<input id='size_in_kw' type='hidden' value='1500'>
```

I've tried this, but it seems to be incomplete:

```
value = soup.find('input', {'id': 'size_in_kw'}).get('value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your second question:

```
if "kW" in item.text:
    itemval = item.find_parent().find_next_sibling().text.strip()
    output.append(itemval)
```

Answer (score 1):

`div.div` selector is too ambiguous, to say the least.

Since, from what it appears, you are up to getting the "Duration at Rated Power (HH:MM)" field value, I would first locate the corresponding `label` and then [find the next](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) text node matching the field format:

```
label = soup.find("label", text="Duration at Rated Power (HH:MM)")
value = label.find_next(text=re.compile(r"\d+:\d+")).strip()
print(value)  # prints 6:00.00
```

(don't forget to import `re` module)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I extend my question into how to also scrape the "Rated Power in kW"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the time you wish to scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.energystorageexchange.org/projects/2") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select("label.new_font"):
    if "HH:MM" in item.text:
        itemval = item.find_parent().find_next_sibling().text.strip()
        print(itemval)
```

Output:

```
6:00.00
```