# Parse Google Maps Markers from JS with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, google-maps, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, coordinates

How can I scrape the lat and lng from such a js block with Python + Beautiful Soup?

> Gmaps.map.markers =
>   [{"id":6,"multi_system":"No","connectedProjects":null,"description":"Kaheawa Wind Project - Younicos
> Country :
>   United States
> Technology Type : Electro-chemical
> Status :
>   Operational","picture":"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569","width":32,"height":32,"lat":20.7983626,"lng":-156.3319253}];

Basic code (see [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956645/beautifulsoup-getting-content-behind-multiple-div-levels)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.energystorageexchange.org/projects/6") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

coord = soup.findAll("Gmaps.map.markers")
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach. Get the `dict` data from that variable and parse it with the `json` module:

```
import json

JS_BLOCK = """Gmaps.map.markers = [{"id":6,"multi_system":"No","connectedProjects":null,"description":"Kaheawa Wind Project - Younicos
Country : United States
Technology Type : Electro-chemical
Status : Operational","picture":"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569","width":32,"height":32,"lat":20.7983626,"lng":-156.3319253}];"""

ini = JS_BLOCK.find("Gmaps.map.markers = [") + len("Gmaps.map.markers = [")
end = JS_BLOCK.find("}];") + 1

data = json.loads(JS_BLOCK[ini:end].replace('\n', ''))

print(data['lat'])
print(data['lng'])
```

**Output**:

```
20.7983626
-156.3319253
```

You can also try a `regex` approach to do this if you want.

Comment: How can I replace JS_BLOCK with my webpage? Neither soup nor page / page.content are working!

Comment: That is a total different question. If you can't parse it with beautifulsoup then try selenium

Comment: Actually, you answered a totally different question :D OP even included the code when he tries to scrape it from the web ^^

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

**Code:**

```
import json
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.energystorageexchange.org/projects/6'

r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

markers_raw = re.search(
    r'Gmaps\.map\.markers'
    r'\s*=\s*'
    r'(.*);', html).group(1)

markers = json.loads(markers_raw)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(markers)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'connectedProjects': None,
  'description': "<a href='/projects/6'>Kaheawa Wind Project - "
                 'Younicos</a><br>Country : United States<br>Technology Type : '
                 'Electro-chemical<br>Status : Operational',
  'height': 32,
  'id': 6,
  'lat': 20.7983626,
  'lng': -156.3319253,
  'multi_system': 'No',
  'picture': 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569',
  'width': 32}]
```

If regular expressions are new to you, you can take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).