# Beautifulsoup multiple div content to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to get the contents of two `div` inside a dictionary in python. The main problem is that I'm able to fetch the first `div` content and the second, but not in the right key:value manner. I'm only able to get the keys back. As such, I know that I need to iterate through the content, but I can't see to get my `for loop` correct.

Following [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956645/beautifulsoup-getting-content-behind-multiple-div-levels) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726507/beautiful-soup-parsing-inline-div-and-p-into-dictionary) cannot get the case done what I'm looking for.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://www.samenvoordeklant.nl/arbeidsmarktregios'
base=requests.get(url, timeout=15)
html=BeautifulSoup(base.text, 'lxml')
regios=html.find_all('div',attrs={'class':['field field--name-node-title field--type-ds field--label-hidden field__item animated','field field--name-field-gemeenten field--type-string-long field--label-hidden field__item animated']})

for regio in regios:
    print({regio.get_text(strip=True)})
```

The result:

```
{'Achterhoek'}
{'Aalten, Berkelland, Bronckhorst, Doetinchem, Montferland, Oost Gelre, Oude IJsselstreek, Winterswijk'}
{'Amersfoort'}
{'Amersfoort, Baarn, Bunschoten, Leusden, Nijkerk, Soest, Woudenberg'}
```

etc.

The result I'm after is:

```
{'Achterhoek':'Aalten', 'Berkelland', 'Bronckhorst', 'Doetinchem', 'Montferland', 'Oost Gelre', 'Oude IJsselstreek', 'Winterswijk'}
{'Amersfoort':'Amersfoort', 'Baarn', 'Bunschoten', 'Leusden', 'Nijkerk', 'Soest', 'Woudenberg'}
```

etc. This allows me to move it afterwards into a `pandas dataframe` more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is with dict and zip of the two lists. Note I have used faster css selectors and avoided using full multi-value of class.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.samenvoordeklant.nl/arbeidsmarktregios')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
result = dict(zip([i.text for i in soup.select('h2 a')], [i.text for i in soup.select('.field--type-string-long')]))
print(result)
# result = {k:v.split(', ') for k, v in result.items()}  ##add this line at end if want list as value rather than string
```

---

Sample pprint output:

[image]

---

If you want a list as the value you can simply add a last line of:

```
result = {k:v.split(', ') for k, v in result.items()}
```

Comment: Hmm, I should have thought about the CSS selectors earlier. Either way, this works splendid!

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `zip`.

**Ex:**

```
regios=html.find_all('div',attrs={'class':['field field--name-node-title field--type-ds field--label-hidden field__item animated','field field--name-field-gemeenten field--type-string-long field--label-hidden field__item animated']})

result = {key.get_text(strip=True): value.get_text(strip=True) for key, value in zip(regios[0::2], regios[1::2])}
pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Achterhoek': 'Aalten, Berkelland, Bronckhorst, Doetinchem, Montferland, Oost '
               'Gelre, Oude IJsselstreek, Winterswijk',
 'Amersfoort': 'Amersfoort, Baarn, Bunschoten, Leusden, Nijkerk, Soest, '
               'Woudenberg',......
```

---

If you need the value as a list of items

**Use:**

```
result = {key.get_text(strip=True): [i.strip() for i in value.get_text(strip=True).split(",")] for key, value in zip(regios[0::2], regios[1::2])}
```

**Output:**

```
{'Achterhoek': ['Aalten',
                'Berkelland',
                'Bronckhorst',
                'Doetinchem',
                'Montferland',
                'Oost Gelre',
                'Oude IJsselstreek',
                'Winterswijk'],
 'Amersfoort': ['Amersfoort',
                'Baarn',
                'Bunschoten',....
```